# Error Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

When executing the command `npm run start: dev`  with migrations configured I receive the error import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm"; SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: ormconfig.ts
`const config: ConnectionOptions = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT), 
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,       
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,  
    entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],  
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    migrationsRun: true,
    migrations: [__dirname + '/../migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: './migrations',
    }
}
export = config;`

Comment: app.module.ts `ConfigModule.forRoot(), 
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({...ormconfig, 
      keepConnectionAlive: true, 
      autoLoadEntities: true}),`

Comment: package.json `"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./src/ormconfig.ts",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n",
    "migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run",   
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm migration:revert"`

Comment: migrations work correctly

Comment: If I remove the migrations files, the command `npm run start: dev` works fine.

Comment: I solved it by moving my migrations folder from the root to /src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by moving the migrations folder inside src.